# Can someone provide an example for this statement in java "a collection is eagerly constructed "?

Tags: java, java-8

Collection is constructed when we add elements to it. Isn't it ?

Comment: All my programming is eager.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understood your statement

Comment: Can you give more context? When did you see this message? What were you attempting to do? Can you post the code that caused the message?

Comment: No, a collection is constructed when you call the constructor.

Comment: user754657 - nicomp's "statement" is a joke. ( Literally, not metaphorically.  As a joke, it is not a joke :-) )

Comment: Found this statement in book 'Java 8 in action' collection is eagerly constructed.

Comment: Please provide more context if you want a decent explanation.  Is this referring the behavior of specific methods?

Comment: @stephen Book states "Collection is eagerly constructed whereas stream is constructed on demand" So i am little confused with this statement. I think collection is created when we initialize it and add some elements to it, which is kind of constructed on demand and thereof collection is NOT eagerly constructed.

Comment: That is not sufficient context to understand what the book is talking about.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your collection implementation.  `ArrayList` and `HashSet`, for example, are always eagerly constructed, but that's not required by the `Collection` contract and there are many other `Collection` implementations that are not necessarily eagerly constructed. For example, the return value of Guava's [`Lists.transform`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)), which applies the function to the source element only when explicitly requested; that's often referred to as *lazy* evaluation (as opposed to eager).